# Issue with calling multiple JSON files

Tags: jquery, json

So i have looked around and found some good information on how to call 2 json files using jquery. While I am able to call both files now I am getting the following error: var weather = data.data.weather;

If I comment out one of the variables (dataUrl2) that calls in a json file then it works with no problem. Below is a sample of the js

```
    var zipcode = '27560';
    var appid = '96afa96cadeb7165258ae95b77fdc';
    var startdate = '2015-10-01';
    var enddate = '2015-10-31';
    var timeperiod ='24';           

    var dataUrl = '//api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q='+ zipcode +'&format=json&date='+ startdate +'&enddate='+ enddate +'&tp='+ timeperiod +'&key='+ appid    

    var dataUrl2 = '//westbrookfl.com/wp-content/plugins/CSAnalytics/lib/data/data-ChannelData.php'

    //Creates Table for Citation Data
        jQuery.when(
            jQuery.getJSON(dataUrl),
            jQuery.getJSON(dataUrl2)
        ).then(function (data, datatwo) {
            console.log(data, datatwo); 
            var citationHTML = '';
            jQuery.each(data, function (i) {
            var weather = data.data.weather;
                for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; ++i) {
                    citationHTML += '<li id="day'+[i]+'" class="day"><div class="date">' + weather[i].date + '</div><div class="svg-icon"><img src="' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value + '" /></div><div class="data-wrap col2"><p class="data hi-temp"><span>' + weather[i].maxtempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p><p class="data lo-temp"><span>' + weather[i].mintempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p></div><p class="data desc">' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherDesc[0].value + '</p></li>';
                }
            });
            jQuery('#citation_report').append(citationHTML);
        });
```

Here is fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/joseph_a_garcia/s41kr5hj/1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you are getting from `dataUrl2 ` getJSON? Does that getJSON need any param?

Comment: If you take the url: //westbrookfl.com/wp-content/plugins/CSAnalytics/lib/data/data-ChannelData.php you can view the response. I do have call data from this URL but i havent gotten that far yet.

Comment: I am not able to access that URL!

Comment: Is it remotely accessible?

Comment: Yes it is, its a public URL that just creates a json array.

Comment: sorry but I am not able to access that!

Comment: Can you please set this on that page `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>`? and let me know, I'll try again!

Comment: Here is a sample of the json: [{"channelGrouping":"Direct","sessions":"490","percentNewSessions":"74.6938775510204","newUsers":"366","bounceRate":"59.795918367346935","pageviewsPerSession":"2.3551020408163263","avgSessionDuration":"141.21020408163264","goalConversionRateAll":"5.918367346938775","goalCompletionsAll":"29","goalValueAll":"1300.0"}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93982/discussion-between-deepak-biswal-and-phantom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/s41kr5hj/48/).

**JS**

```
var zipcode = '27560';
        var appid = '96afa96cadeb7165258ae95b77fdc';
        var startdate = '2015-10-01';
        var enddate = '2015-10-31';
        var timeperiod ='24';           

        var dataUrl = '//api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q='+ zipcode +'&format=json&date='+ startdate +'&enddate='+ enddate +'&tp='+ timeperiod +'&key='+ appid    

        var dataUrl2 = '//westbrookfl.com/wp-content/plugins/CSAnalytics/lib/data/data-ChannelData.php'

        //Creates Table for Citation Data       
$.when(
    $.getJSON(dataUrl),
    $.getJSON(dataUrl2)
).done (function (data, data2) {
    var data = data[0].data;
    console.log(data);
                var citationHTML = '';
                jQuery.each(data, function (i) {
                var weather = data.weather;
                    for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; ++i) {
                        citationHTML += '<li id="day'+[i]+'" class="day"><div class="date">' + weather[i].date + '</div><div class="svg-icon"><img src="' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value + '" /></div><div class="data-wrap col2"><p class="data hi-temp"><span>' + weather[i].maxtempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p><p class="data lo-temp"><span>' + weather[i].mintempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p></div><p class="data desc">' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherDesc[0].value + '</p></li>';
                    }
                });
                jQuery('#citation_report').append(citationHTML);
            });
```

**NOTE:** The `weather` object reference was not correct in your codes. I have added this line `var data = data[0].data;` and it's working fine! You can get second getJSON data in `data2` variable if you want to use that!

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/s41kr5hj/51/) it is working with `data2` object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass as many arguments to the `done` function that you pass to `.when`, so `done(function(data1, data2) {...`

Best.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but the error remains. Having a hard time trying to wrap my head around this.